# How do you return multiple results from a mongoDB aggregate() query?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is a query which runs a match, and then returns the number of unique entries in a specific field:

```
db.sequences.aggregate([{$match: {id: 5}}, {$group : {_id : "$field"} }, {$group: {_id:1, count: {$sum : 1 }}}])
```

However, what if I wanted to return multiple values, such as a count of all of the documents in the original match aggregation, the first 50 documents in the original match, and the number of unique entries of a field2 for the same matched set of documents?

Would I be able to write 1 aggregate query that returns all of these values?

Comment: can you post a sample document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two separate `$group` stages. First `$group` by the `filed` field, and then `$push` the resulting documents into an array and at the same time accumulate `count` from each document, to obtain the total sum.

```
db.sequences.aggregate(
   [
      {$match: {id: 5}}, 
      {$group : 
         {
            _id : "$field", 
            count: {$sum: 1}
         }
      },
      {$group : 
         {
            _id : null, 
            totalNumberOfMatches: {$sum: '$count'},
            totalNumberOfUniqueMatches: {$sum: 1},
            uniqueMatchesField:
               {
                  $push:
                     {
                        field: '$_id',
                        count: '$count'
                     }
               }
         }
      },
   ]
)
```

Comment: So, what I want, is both the total number of documents that come from the match (e.g. the sum of all of the sums), and also the number of uniques. How do I get both?

Comment: Ideally, the returned document would be something like {totalNumberOfMatches: N, totalNumberOfUniqueMatches: J, uniqueMatchesField: ["unique_result1","unique_result2"...]}

Comment: ok, now I got the point behind the second `$group`. Yes you can do that, let me edit the answer.

Comment: @collisionTwo if an answer solves the problem in you question, you can accept it, so that other visitors see that.

Comment: as the final part of the question: is it possible to add a limit to that push, so that only the first n documents are shown?

Comment: You cannot do that in the scope of `$push`, but instead you can use [`$limit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stage before `$push`.